# Fastest way checking for COM ports

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, serial-port

I need to check for available COM ports in my application:

I created two ways to do this.

**Method 1:**

```
public List<string> GetAllPortsForeach()
{
     var allPorts = new List<string>();
     foreach (String portName in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames())
     {
           allPorts.Add(portName);
     }
     return allPorts;
}
```

**Method 2:**

```
public List<string> GetAllPortsForLoop()
{
      var allPorts = new List<string>();
       for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++)
       {
           string comPortName = "COM" + Convert.ToString(i);
           SerialPort sp = new SerialPort(comPortName);
           try
           {
               sp.Open();
               allPorts.Add(comPortName);               
               sp.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
        return allPorts;
}
```

Which is the fastest? Which should I use and why?

Comment: Profile it and tell us. In general the more inbuilt functionality you use in .net the better.

Comment: Method 1 because it isn't trying to open the ports, which is time consuming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 1st one. It reads all available port names from registry. To be more precise, it is just enough to use `SerialPort.GetPortNames`, if you're not planning to add any custom port name to the list.

The 2nd one:

- limited by port number (port name can be "COM20", but the total numbers of ports in the system will be, e.g., 4)
- exception-based (this is ugly and slower).

Comment: even faster would be `new List<string>(SerialPort.GetPortNames())` or the `SerialPort.GetPortNames().ToList()` LINQ method

Comment: @FallingBullets: it won't, because `List<T>` ctor in fact does the same things inside (of course, if you're not calculating processor cycles). At the same time, exceptions are really slow.

Comment: ok, faster was the wrong word, but it's slightly cleaner code.